# Combine collection of lenses

Tags: scala, monocle-scala

Monocle is a great library (and not the only one) which implements lenses pattern, which is great if we have to change one field in huge nested object. Like in example http://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/

```
case class Street(number: Int, name: String)
case class Address(city: String, street: Street)
case class Company(name: String, address: Address)
case class Employee(name: String, company: Company)
```

The following boilerplate

```
employee.copy(
  company = employee.company.copy(
    address = employee.company.address.copy(
      street = employee.company.address.street.copy(
        name = employee.company.address.street.name.capitalize // luckily capitalize exists
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Can easily be replaced  with

```
import monocle.macros.syntax.lens._

employee
  .lens(_.company.address.street.name)
  .composeOptional(headOption)
  .modify(_.toUpper)
```

Which is great. As far as I understand, macros magic converts everything exactly to the same code as above.

However, what if I want to combine several actions? What if I want to change street name, address city and company name at the same time with one call? Like the following:

```
employee.copy(
  company = employee.company.copy(
    address = employee.company.address.copy(
      street = employee.company.address.street.copy(
        name = employee.company.address.street.name.capitalize // luckily capitalize exists
      ),
      city = employee.company.address.city.capitalize
    ),
    name = employee.company.name.capitalize
  )
)
```

If I just reuse lenses here, I would have the following code:

```
employee
  .lens(_.company.address.street.name).composeOptional(headOption).modify(_.toUpper)
  .lens(_.company.address.city).composeOptional(headOption).modify(_.toUpper)
  .lens(_.company.name).composeOptional(headOption).modify(_.toUpper)
```

Which will eventually be translated to **THREE** `employee.copy(...).copy(...).copy(...)` invocations, not just **ONE** `employee.copy(...)`. How to make it better?

Furthermore, it would be really great to apply a sequence of operations. Like sequence of pairs `Seq[(Lens[Employee, String], String => String)]` where first element is a lens pointing to the correct field and the second one is a function which modifies it. It will help to build such sequence of operations from the outside. For the above example:

```
val operations = Seq(
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.address.street.name) -> {s: String => s.capitalize},
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.address.city) -> {s: String => s.capitalize},
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.name) -> {s: String => s.capitalize}
)
```

or something similar...

Answer (score 11):

> As far as I understand, macros magic converts everything exactly to the same code as above.

It doesn't.

This simple code:

```
employee.lens(_.name)
  .modify(_.capitalize)
```

Becomes something along the lines of that monstrosity *:

```
monocle.syntax.ApplyLens(employee,
    new monocle.PLens[Employee, Employee, String, String] {
      def get(e: Employee): String = e.name;
      def set(s: String): Employee => Employee = _.copy(s);
      def modify(f: String => String): Employee => Employee = e => e.copy(f(e.name))
    }
}).modify(_.capitalize)
```

Which is quite far from simple

```
employee.copy(name = employee.name.capitalize)
```

and includes three redundant objects (anonymous lens class, ApplyLens for syntax sugar and lambda returned from `modify`). And we skipped more by using `capitalize` directly instead of composing with `headOption`.

So no, there is no free dinner. Most of the time, however, it's good enough and nobody cares about extra lens objects and intermediate results.

---

### Multiple operations

You can build a Traversal (collection lens) from multiple lenses if their types align (here it's `Employee` to `String`)

```
val capitalizeAllFields = Traversal.applyN(
  GenLens[Employee](_.name),
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.address.street.name),
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.address.city),
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.name)
).modify(_.capitalize)
```

This will still call `copy` multiple times. For efficiency, you can use `Traversal.apply4` et al. varieties, which will require you to write that `copy` manually (and I'm too lazy to do it now).

Finally, if you want to apply various transformations to different types of fields, you are supposed to use the fact that `modify` and `set` return a function of type `Employee => Employee`. For your example that would be:

```
val operations = Seq(
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.address.street.name).modify(_.capitalize),
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.address.street.number).modify(_ + 42),
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.name).set("No Company Inc.")
)

val modifyAll = Function.chain(operations)

// does all above operations of course, with two extra copy calls
modifyAll(employee)
```

---

* - this is simplified output from `desugar` in Ammonite-REPL. I skipped `modifyF`, btw